# Using urlencode for Devanagari text

Tags: python, urllib

The following code:

```
import simplejson,urllib,urllib2  

query=[u'नेपाल']
urlbase="http://search.twitter.com/search.json"
values={'q':query[0]}
data=urllib.urlencode(values)
req=urllib2.Request(urlbase,data)
response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
json=simplejson.load(response)
print json
```

throws exception:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file ques.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

The code works if `query` contains standard ASCII characters. I tried looking at the suggested link but couldn't figure out how to specify encoding for Devanagari characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the UTF-8 header to your file to tell the Python interpreter that there are unicode literals. You also have to encode the parameters as UTF-8. Here's a working version:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import simplejson,urllib,urllib2  

query=[u'नेपाल']
urlbase="http://search.twitter.com/search.json"
values={'q':query[0].encode('utf-8')}
data=urllib.urlencode(values)
req=urllib2.Request(urlbase,data)
response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
json=simplejson.load(response)
print json
```

Comment: By the way, I had to write 'नेपाल' instead of u'नेपाल' to get it to work.