# how to check the utf-8 equivalent value of a character in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to know how to find the utf-8 equivalent of a tamil character. Is there any function for it? Can you give the syntax.

```
for line in f:
    words = line.strip().split() 
    for word1, word2 in zip(words, words[1:]): 
            if word1 == '1' and word2 == "கோடி":
                ff.write("onru\n")
                ff.write(word2+'\n')
            else:
                ff.write(word1+'\n')
                ff.write(word2+'\n')
```

But it gives, SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file replacement.py on line 5, but no encoding declared. So how to read the non-ascii characters or how to read the tamil words. mainly how to compare and check. Thanx in advance.

Comment: see if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672057/using-urlencode-for-devanagari-text

Comment: Have you added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the source file as described in PEP 0263?

Comment: @MichalNikas I have added the utf-8 header, it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if its technically making any difference, but i just removed the double quotes and replaced them with single quotes and now my pgm works. it is doing the comparison correctly. now am giving as'கோடி' instead of "கோடி". I tried u'கோடி, u'/கோடி, u"கோடி. all of them were giving errors.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens before Python starts executing the file, because it detects a non-ASCII characters. (By the way, this is a Python 2-only issue, so you should probably remove the `python-3.x` tag from your post).

To tell Python the file is encoded in UTF-8, you should add this at the beginning of the file (as defined in [PEP 263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)):

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

Comment: @Valentine Lorentz: i have added the header already, it still gives an error. actually when i add the utf 8 header it helps me to read and write tamil files,I have been doing that, but am not able to do comparison on tamil word.